# Accessing authorization information in web.config

Tags: .net, authorization, roleprovider

I'm writing a custom role provider and I need programmatic access the authorization information stored in the web.config. 
Certain section of the site are only accessible by certain roles. I would like to find out which roles can access a page and/or which page a certain role can access.

I can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access any information stored such as ConnectionStrings,AppSettings and other defined values in web.config by WebConfigurationManager class in System.Web.Security namespace.

Let's say you have defined and authorization section as:

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="admin,moderator" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization></system.web>
```

The section you just created means users who has **admin** and/or **moderator** roles can access pages within and deny **everyone** (anonymous) who attempts to access without login information.

In order to that just call out WebConfigurationManager's GetSection method as

```
AuthorizationSection auth = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/authorization") as AuthorizationSection;
```

AuthorizationSection class will give you 
`Rules` collection which is precisely what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't find any `Rules` collection on the `AuthenticationSection` object... ?

Comment: AuthorizationSection has the Rules collection.
I spelled the name of class incorrectly. It's not AuthenticationSection but AuthorizationSection,i edited my post to verify the error you mentioned,thank you for noticing this to me.