# Check if authorization is needed on current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, authorization

In `web.config` we can set authorization option individually for locations:

```
<location path="request.ashx">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <allow users="*" />
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>
```

How to get this option from code?

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Comment: What about this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848086/authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I hope you are searching for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240552/accessing-authorization-information-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

Better than using Authorize attribute, i think that using an if condition would be far better.

```
If(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    If(User.Identity.IsInRole=="admin")
    {
        return view("Secret");
    }
    else
    {
            return view("NotAllowed")
    }
}
else
{
    return View("NeedAuth");
}
```

If user is suddenly redirected to loginpage as in attribute, he may think it as an error in website, but this way you would be able to clearly tell the user that he needs to Authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("Your Path");
        }
    }
```